# The kinematics plugin (arm) failed to load. Error: MultiLibraryClassLoader

Tags: ros

The kinematics plugin (arm) failed to load. Error: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type campusrover_arm_arm::IKFastKinematicsPlugin as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()

i create a fastik but it can't find the slover.

Comment: What does your code look like? No one here will be able to help without seeing code.